# Jaxb creating boolean method accessor names with "get" instead of "is" prefix

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, xsd

Using jaxb2-maven-plugin and jaxb-xjc, while generating classes jaxb creates boolean accessors with get prefix however I want it to create with java convention "is".

here is the xsd:

```
    <xsd:complexType name="QueryWorkgroupRequestType">
    <xsd:sequence>
    ...
        <xsd:element name="disabled" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    ...
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and the created method is;

```
public Boolean getDisabled() {
    return disabled;
}
```

But I want instead;

```
public Boolean isDisabled() {
    return disabled;
}
```

I tried

`<xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings enableJavaNamingConventions="true" generateIsSetMethod="true"/>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>`
but no chance.

** **SOLVED** **

**Well at last I could sort out the problem, maven was using jdk 1.8, somehow using 1.8 masses it up. Using 1.6 fixed it, works as desired now.**

Comment: Using 1.6 hasn't "fixed" anything - earlier versions of the JAXB reference implementation [had a bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-131) whereby they incorrectly generated "is" accessors instead of "get" ones for `Boolean` properties.  This bug was fixed but it looks like the Java 6 you're using contains the buggy version of JAXB.

Comment: either case, there is a code working with the 'buggy' version and there might be ones having the same problem. I am not sure which one is buggy as of using enableJavaNamingConventions didn't work for jdk1.8 neither so i feel like there still is an ambiguity.

Answer (score 8):

The `is` prefix for Java Bean accessor methods is only valid for properties of the *primitive* type `boolean`.  For all other types (including the `java.lang.Boolean` reference type) the only valid prefix that will be recognised as a bean property accessor is `get`.

If the element were not nullable (i.e. it didn't have `minOccurs="0"`) then it would be bound to a property of type `boolean` rather than `Boolean` and *would* get an `is` accessor.

Comment: unfortunately it has to be Boolean

Comment: @hevi in which case, unfortunately, it _has_ to be `get` - an `isSomething` method returning a type other than `boolean` does _not_ qualify as a Java Bean property accessor.

Comment: There is a bug in XJC which generates is* for Boolean, which is wrong, according to the Java Bean spec. You can pass the XJC flag `-enableIntrospection` to generate the correct getters. See https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/131